# Example of a function $u\in L^\infty(0,T,H^1)$ such that $u_t\notin L^\infty(0,T,H^1)$

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, sobolev-spaces, distribution-theory

Could someone give me an example of a function $u\in L^\infty(0,T,H^1)$ such that $u_t$ exists (in the distributional sense), $u_t\in L^\infty(0,T,L^2)$ and $u_t\notin L^\infty(0,T,H^1)$?

Thanks.

*EDIT (to add context).* *Let $f_0\in H^1$. If $u(t)=f_0$ (constant function with respect to $t$) then $u\in L^\infty(0,T,H^1)$ and $u_t\in L^\infty(0,T,H^1)$. If $u(t)=\int_0^t f_0\;dt$, the same occurs. These are simple examples in which I've thought. Essentially, my question is: How to derive $u$ with respect to $t$ affects the regularity of $u(t)$ with respect to $x$? I think that examples can help me to understand it.*

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: @Tomás Please, read my edit in the post.

Comment: Could you please say me what is the definition of $u_t$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X$ be a Banach space and $u\in L^1(0,T,X)$. We say that $u'\in L^1(0,T,X)$ the weak derivative of $u$ if $$\int_0^T u(t)\phi'(t)dt=-\int_0^T u'(t)\phi(t)dt,\forall\ \phi\in C_0^\infty(0,T).$$

According to this definition, the problem is not that $u'(t)$ does not belong to $H^1$,  it does belong to $H^1$. The question is, if it belong to $L^\infty$, i.e. $$u\in L^\infty (0,T,H^1),\ u'\in L^\infty(0,T,L^2)\ \mbox{implies}\ u'\in L^\infty(0,T,H^1)? $$

Note that $u'\in L^\infty(0,T,L^2)$ is equivalently to $$\sup_{t\in (0,T)} \|u'(t)\|_2<\infty,$$

while $u'\in L^\infty(0,T,H^1)$ is equivalently to $$\sup_{t\in (0,T)} \|u'(t)\|_{1,2}<\infty.$$

These are two different things. Now I think you can construct a example which satisfies your requirements .

Comment: Your answer was helpful. Thanks. I've a related question [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/911285/find-u0-t-to-h2-such-that-u0-u-0-in-h2-and-u-t0-u-1-in-h1)? I appreciate if you can help me.